# Сегодняшний день - тавтология?

Tags: грамотная-речь, тавтология

Слово "сегодня" происходит от "сего дня", то есть конкретно в этот день. Но часто можно слышать выражение "сегодняшний день".
Честно говоря, я раньше никогда не задумывалась над этим оборотом, но ведь действительно выходит, что это тавтология. Если "сегодня", то и так речь о настоящем дне.
То есть хочется узнать, допустим ли оборот "сегодняшний день"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Некоторые устойчивые тавтологические выражения ошибкой не считаются, потому что закрепились в речи именно в таком, не совсем правильном, виде: приснился сон, в игрушки играть. "Никто не станет браковать такие, например, широко употреби­тельные выражения, как истинная правда, всякая всячи­на, слыхом не слыхивать, сиднем сидеть, криком кри­чать, вокруг да около и т.п., хотя они, в сущности, явля­ются тавтологическими" (из работы по проблеме).

Думаю, что выражение "сегодняшний день" тоже закрепилось в языке и уже не считается  речевой ошибкой, хотя тавтология налицо.

Answer (score 4):

В нашей речи часто  встречаются следующие выражения:  на сегодняшний день (на текущий день, в настоящий момент),  жить сегодняшним днем (текущим днем, не думая о будущем).

В этих примерах выражение "сегодняшний день"  является более удобной грамматической формой по сравнению с наречием "сегодня", поэтому  заменяет его в различных значениях (текущий день, настоящее время).   И конечно, "сегодняшний день" имеет  содержание, отличное от значения слова "день", поэтому это не плеоназм.

В современном языке слова "день и сегодня" не являются однокоренными, хотя с точки зрения этимологии они связаны между собой. Поэтому это не тавтология.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что "сегодняшний день" если не тавтология, то некоторое косноязычие.
По двум причинам.  
Во-первых, никто не отменял "день нынешний", "сей день", "текущий", "наступивший" и проч. Зачем ещё громоздить длинную однокоренную конструкцию?!
И во-вторых, сравните "сегодняшняя ночь" и "сегодняшний день". По логике, должны быть аналогичные значения. Однако, второе используется совсем не в том значении. Обидно...

К сожалению, иногда приходится считаться с тем, что язык принимает подобные неудобоваримые конструкции вопреки логике. Так что бороться серьезно с этим сочетанием я не стал бы.

Answer (score 1):

"День" может быть не только сегодняшним, но и вчерашним. Поэтому, честно говоря, тавтологии я здесь не вижу:)

Comment: Не понимаю Вашей логики. Спрашивают не тавтология ли "день сего дня" (= сегодняшний день). Масло тоже может быть сливочным, оливковым или подсолнечным, но масло масляное - все равно тавтология.

Answer (score 0):

Любой любитель тавтологии, всегда найдёт оправдание для любой тавтологии. А посему скажу, что "вчерашнее вчера", "завтрашнее завтра", и "сегодняшний день" - банальная тавтология.